# Multithreaded program hangs on control method call

Tags: multithreading, c++-cli, deadlock, race-condition

I've got a UI with 2 buttons and a textbox.

When the user presses the "Receive" button, a thread is started for an infinite work loop (receiving and printing messages from multicast). When the user presses the "Stop" button, the thread is given it's "kill flag" and then the program waits for the `Join()` to finish.

That infinite work loop calls back to the UI textbox with a `SetTextBoxText(System::String)` method. This is causing a race condition. Sometimes, the thread finishes the `Join()` just fine. Others, the program hangs forever on the `Join()`.

I believe this is because when the UI thread calls `Join()` on its work thread, the work thread may be in the middle of its loop and is trying to invoke a locked thread. The UI thread is waiting for the `Join()` and is unable to do anything (like `SetTextBoxText`).

So, race-condition or deadlock, I need a way to check if the `control` is usable. If it is, then call the method to print like normal. If it is not usable, then don't try to call the `SetTextBoxText` method and continue like normal.

---

Code time, I'm actually using a `UserControl`, not a separate textbox, button1, and button2. I call the `UserControl` "MyUserControl". It contains the following code:

```
System::Void MyUserControl::buttonReceive_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
{
    //each MyUserControl has their own myThread
    this->myThread = gcnew System::Threading::Thread(gcnew System::Threading::ThreadStart(this, &MyUserControl::WorkLoop));
    this->workLoopFlag = true;
    this->myThread->Start();
}

void MyUserControl::WorkLoop()
{
    while (this->workLoopFlag == true)
    {
        System::Threading::Thread::BeginCriticalRegion();
        //this->myThread->BeginCriticalRegion();
        Process();
        //this->myThread->EndCriticalRegion();
        System::Threading::Thread::EndCriticalRegion();
    }
}
```

---

```
void EntityStatePduProcessor::Process()
{
    //These 2 lines are for getting the correct MyUserControl to edit. Stored in GlobalVars::myList
    ThreadPredicate^ threadPred = gcnew ThreadPredicate(System::Threading::Thread::CurrentThread->ManagedThreadId);
    UserControlDataCollection^ userControlDataColl = GlobalVars::myList->Find(gcnew System::Predicate<UserControlDataCollection^>(threadPred, &ThreadPredicate::IsMatch));

    System::Threading::Thread::BeginCriticalRegion();
    if (userControlDataColl != nullptr) //should only happen after killing a thread
    {
        MyUserControl^ controlToEdit = (MyUserControl^)System::Windows::Forms::Control::FromHandle(userControlDataColl->control);

            if (controlToEdit != nullptr)
            {
                //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                controlToEdit->SetTextBoxConsoleText("a system::string to place into the textbox");
                //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            }
            else
            {
                System::Windows::Forms::MessageBox::Show("controlToEdit == nullptr");
            }
    }
    System::Threading::Thread::EndCriticalRegion();
}
```

---

```
delegate void MyStringDelegate(System::String ^ text);
void MyUserControl::SetTextBoxConsoleText(System::String^ input)
{
    if (this->InvokeRequired) // (this->consoleTextBox->InvokeRequired)
    {
        MyStringDelegate^ myStrDel = gcnew MyStringDelegate(this, &MyUserControl::SetTextBoxConsoleText);
        this->Invoke(myStrDel, gcnew array<Object^> { input });
    }
    else
    {
        this->textBoxConsole->Text = input;
        this->textBoxConsole->Refresh();
    }
}

System::Void MyUserControl::buttonStop_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
{
    this->workLoopFlag = false; // kill the endless while loop

    this->myThread->Join();
}
```

---

I tried to post the code in chronological order and only include the essentials while explaining the gaps in `//comments`.

The code that causes the hang is in the 3rd method shown `Process()` outlined with `//~~~`.

How do I correctly ensure that the `controlToEdit` is still able to access and not just waiting on a `Join()`?

Comment: You left out the most important code, we can't see what SetTextBoxConsoleText() does.  Crystal ball says that you use Invoke(), that is a mistake and likely to deadlock when you hang the UI thread.  Use BeginInvoke() instead.  Also, a *bool* is not a proper synchronization primitive.  AutoResetEvent is.

Comment: Using BeginInvoke() instead of Invoke() seems to have fixed it. I read up on the asynchronous BeginInvoke() a while ago and apparently didn't bother to use that instead of Invoke(). I hadn't even looked into that anymore. Gold star to @HansPassant for finding the solution without even seeing the code that was broken. Wow.